# Get image src with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

```
<img src="../img/arnold.png" alt="Arnold">
```

How do I get with jQuery absolute path of this image?

`img.attr("src")` gives me just "**../img/arnold.png**", should give something like "**http://site.com/data/2011/img/arnold.png**" (full url).

Comment: It's depend on how did you assign image path in image src.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
alert( $('img')[0].src );
```

this might do the trick... but not sure about cross browser....

[demo in here](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/H6vBx/)

also try [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop) of jQuery 1.6..

```
alert( $('img').prop('src') );
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/caVYd/)

Comment: +1 This is very neat - Steve this looks like the correct answer to me

Comment: Great answer. What should I do, if i want **src** of all the images in a page?

Comment: @V15HMAY: you can use `.map()` like this... http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/caVYd/109/ look at the console on that sample link.. `.map()`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that you can get it with jQuery, but you can get it with just the native JavaScript image object.

```
var getSrc = function(imgSource) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = imgSource;
    return img.src;
};
```

Just call it with `x = getSrc(srcAttribute)` or something similar where your parameter is the string or literal holding the src you currently have in your html/image. It will return something like http://your/site/path/to/image.jpg

http://jsfiddle.net/BradleyStaples/cQMjQ/

Comment: Hmmm...not very efficient, compared to the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6952240/1105203) but it is a novel approach!

Answer (score 0):

> Give current clicked image source in jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('body').on('click','img',function(){
                alert('it works');
                var imgsrc=$(this).attr('src');
                alert(imgsrc);
});
});
```